# Application.Evaluate(item) always uses first row as base, why?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of table-based formulas saved in a list, that I would like to run on each row until I get a result.

When ever I use below code, the formulas however, always use the first row of the table as base.

```
For Each rng In sqltabel.ListColumns("column1").DataBodyRange.Rows
    For Each item In arr    
        rng.Offset(0, sqlcolumn) = Application.Evaluate(item)
```

A formula in the 'arr' could look like

```
=IFS(tabel1[@[column10]]="stack";"overflow")
```

So if the first row, column10, contains "stack" all other rows' formulas will end on the same formula and post "overflow" as result.
What am I doing wrong, or am I not understanding the Evaluate application?

As a quick-fix I'm using the below code, but I was hoping to avoid it, as it slows down the macro.

```
rng.Offset(0, sqlcolumn).FormulaArray = _
item
```

Comment: In the formula you evaluate, `=IFS(tabel1[@[column10]]="stack";"overflow")`, there is no provision for looping through `Tabel1[@[column10]]`  Therefore the formula evaluates the columns first item. Why don't you just do this calculation in VBA?

Comment: Thank you Variatus for your post. If I use the FormulaArray, Excel knows to look in the row of the cell formula. I can't quite understand why it would be different if you evaluate a formula.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that :-)  However, I don't think there is a win in this game. If `Evaluate` can be made to do what you want it won

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that :-)  However, I don't think there is a win in this game. If `Evaluate` can be pushed to do what you want it will not change the way VBA is used or `Evaluate` is used in VBA. On the other hand, if the effort fails, Microsoft will not admit to a fault in its Excel program. The quick fix is the one you already use, and the proper solution is to   fill the target cell with a result calculated by VBA.